# Fisher information and the "surface area of the typical set"

Tags: information-theory

On page 331 of "Elements of Information Theory" (1991), author says that while entropy is related to the volume of the typical set, Fisher information is related to the surface area of the typical set, but I can't find anything more on this...can anyone explain this connection?

Comment: It seems from the question, the entropy/volume connection is established, similarly we know of the volume/surface area connection. So the point here is to connect the trace of the FI to entropy. Or am I missing the point of your question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

UPDATE

Tough crowd.  :)  For a concise account of connecting the trace of the Fisher matrix to surface area, please see section 4 ("Isoperimetric Inequalities") in the paper below.  The crucial part is establishing the relation between differential entropy and the trace of the Fisher matrix, which the authors prove in the appendix.

- [On the similarity of the entropy power inequality and the Brunn-Minkowski inequality](http://statistics.stanford.edu/~ckirby/techreports/NSF/COV%20NSF%2048.pdf)

---

The basic intuition is through the isoperimetric inequality for the surface area of a sphere maximizing the volume.  We can arrive at a similar relationship concerning the trace of the Fisher information matrix and the entropy w.r.t the Gaussian.  The following may be helpful.

- [Information Theoretic Inequalities for Contoured Probability Distributions](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.35.7743)